# I want bitmap Left and right side edges to be blurred out

Tags: java, android, image-processing, android-canvas

I have seen many answers on stackoverflow and tried many possible combinations but still i  can't get the expected bllureed image as shown below:
[Side Blur Edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJAvy.jpg)

The code i tried (using canvas and then overlaying bot images)

```
public static Bitmap blur(Context context, Bitmap image) {
    int width = Math.round(image.getWidth());
    int height = Math.round(image.getHeight());

    Bitmap inputBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, false);
    Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(inputBitmap);

    RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(context);
    ScriptIntrinsicBlur theIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
    Allocation tmpIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, inputBitmap);
    Allocation tmpOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, outputBitmap);
    theIntrinsic.setRadius(25);
    theIntrinsic.setInput(tmpIn);
    theIntrinsic.forEach(tmpOut);
    tmpOut.copyTo(outputBitmap);

    return outputBitmap;
}

public static Bitmap overlayBitmap(Bitmap bitmapBackground, Bitmap bitmapImage) {
    Bitmap resized_bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapImage, (int) (bitmapBackground.getWidth()*0.8), bitmapBackground.getWidth(),true);

    Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapBackground.getWidth(), bitmapBackground.getHeight(), bitmapBackground.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapBackground, new Matrix(), null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(resized_bitmap,bitmapBackground.getWidth()/5,bitmapBackground.getHeight()/5, null);
    return bmOverlay;
}
```

Not getting the desired blur using this code tried several combinations but still no success.

Comment: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-blur-images-efficiently-with-androids-renderscript

Comment: Not solving my issue

Answer (score 0):

When Trying to blur out both sides of my ImageView I used the following code:

```
  private void applyBlur(final ImageView image) {
    image.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            image.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            image.buildDrawingCache();

            Bitmap bmp = image.getDrawingCache();
            blur(bmp, image);
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
private void blur(Bitmap mBitmap, View view) {
    long startMs = System.currentTimeMillis();

    float radius = 20;

    Bitmap overlay = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) (view.getMeasuredWidth()),
            (int) (view.getMeasuredHeight()), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(overlay);



    canvas.translate(-view.getLeft(), -view.getTop());
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 100, 0,null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, -100, 0,null);
    RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(getApplicationContext());

    Allocation overlayAlloc = Allocation.createFromBitmap(
            rs, overlay);

    ScriptIntrinsicBlur blur = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(
            rs, overlayAlloc.getElement());

    blur.setInput(overlayAlloc);

    blur.setRadius(radius);

    blur.forEach(overlayAlloc);

    overlayAlloc.copyTo(overlay);

    view.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(
            getResources(), overlay));

    rs.destroy();
}//end blur
```

The key to blurring out both sides of the ImageView instead of just the left side

changing the 2nd parameter in the `canvas.drawBitmap` to a negative value

eg 100 becomes -100

so after  `canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 100, 0,null);` you add `canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, -100, 0,null);`

Hope this helps.